# Do PHP offer .NET similar frameworks?

Tags: c#, php

To the function oriented PHP style of coding

i.e. `is_empty($text)`

I prefer the object oriented syntax of c#:

i.e. `string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)`

Is there a way to try to shorten the distance between c# and PHP?

Comment: Yeah, you can build your own `sting` class with a `IsNullOrEmpty` method on it, but as far as I'm aware, there are no frameworks that go that far into OOP

Comment: Looks like a very weird choice.. I strongly think OOP is a good enhanchement in IT development..

Comment: it isn't a weird choice, they are two very different languages, and handle similar operations differently. PHP will let you make your own kind of framework if you wish to do so, but most won't spend time nitpicking over datatype classes.

Comment: it's not a "choice", more a "very old decision that has impacted the new releases". It may change in the future.

Comment: @Federkun: thanks, ps: how idiotic are downvoters?

Comment: Do you have ever tried https://phalanger.codeplex.com/ ?

Comment: Don't get hung up on a preferred paradigm and forcing every language into it (square peg, round hole), learn and explore how to best utilise the features provided by a given language and decide on a program by program basis which is the most suitable language to use, and what you thing the best [blend of] paradigms to use will be (if there is a choice) within that chosen language.

Answer (score 1):

PHP had functional paradigma for long time, so there are plenty of things, which are solved in this way. Also PHP add types in last year, so there are still long way to improve some things.

But there are already some tools. You can use https://github.com/nette/utils which contains already some usefull OOP classes and more intuitive methods.

Comment: PHP has had types for a good while, so i don't think they were added last year ;)

Comment: Internal dynamic types yeah, but there are lots of fuckups with magic about dynamic types in PHP like "0e2" == "0e1" or md5("240610708") == md5("QNKCDZO") which both return true. In PHP 7+ was added scalar types with strict option which can easily remove that 'bugs' :] That was what i mean.